# ORA-00927: missing equal sign

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Im creating my first sql trigger,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER totalsalary
    AFTER INSERT ON Employee
    FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( NEW.Dno IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
    UPDATE Department
    SET totalSalary totalSalary + NEW.salary
    WHERE Dno = NEW.Dno;
END
;
```

but i got this error message and i dont know how to fix it

```
Error at line 3: PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign

1. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SueldoTotal
2.  AFTER INSERT ON EMPLEADO
3.  FOR EACH ROW
4. WHEN ( NEW.Dno IS NOT NULL )
5. BEGIN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SET totalSalary totalSalary + NEW.salary

You have a **missing equal sign** in the **SET** clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER totalsalary
    AFTER INSERT ON Employee
    FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( NEW.Dno IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
    UPDATE Department
    SET totalSalary = totalSalary + :NEW.salary
    WHERE Dno = :NEW.Dno;
END;
/
```

> NEW.salary

Also, this is incorrect while referencing OLD and NEW values:

```
:NEW.salary
```