# ORA-00927: missing equal sign and bad bind variable errors from trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a problem with this trigger and I don´t understand why it doesn´t work. I have two tables in my database and I want do create a trigger to update the table "mensajes_info" when I modified the table "mensajes"

```
CREATE TABLE ESC.MENSAJES (CODIGO NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  TEXTO VARCHAR2(200),
  TIPO VARCHAR2(30)) ;

CREATE TABLE MENSAJES_INFO ( TIPO VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  CUANTOS_MENSAJES NUMBER(2),
  ULTIMO VARCHAR2(200),
  CONSTRAINT MENSAJES_INFO_PK PRIMARY KEY (TIPO ) ENABLE );

create or replace TRIGGER ACTUALIZA_TB_MENS_INFO 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ESC.MENSAJES 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET(ULTIMO) SELECT :NEW.TEXT0 FROM ESC.MENSAJES;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET(CUANTOS_MENSAJES, ULTIMO)
    ((CUANTOS_MENSAJES)-1, NULL) WHERE :OLD.tipo = tipo;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    IF(:OLD.tipo != :NEW.tipo) THEN
      UPDATE  MENSAJES_INFO SET(CUANTOS_MENSAJES, ULTIMO)         
      (select(CUANTOS_MENSAJES)-1, NULL)  WHERE :OLD.tipo != :NEW.tipo;
    ELSE
      UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET (CUANTOS_MENSAJES, ULTIMO)
      VALUES(select(CUANTOS_MENSAJES)+1, :NEW.TEXT0) WHERE :new.tipo = tipo ;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

I get compilation errors:

Errors for TRIGGER MY_SCHEMA.ACTUALIZA_TB_MENS_INFO:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------------------------
3/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/38     PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
3/45     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TEXT0'
5/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
9/7      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/7     PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
12/7     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/7     PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
13/42    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TEXT0'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just saying it "doesn't work" isn't helpful. Do you get a compilation error, a run-time error when you try to insert/delete the table? Where did you find that syntax for your `update` statements?

Comment: I have different errors, but the code that one is:

Comment: Error(6,38): PL/SQL: ORA-00927: falta el signo de igual

Comment: and another error:

Comment: Error(6,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Please edit your question to add new information, particularly code and errors. It would also be helpful to show English error messages. `ORA-00927: missing equal sign` is because your update statements are malformed, as I hinted at in my previous comment. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30251569/266304) to start with, [and the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm).

Comment: sorry jfor my bad english,

Comment: The code does not compile, so I think I have malformed sentences, but I don´t understnad why  they are badly formed. Oracle says that variable ": new.text0" does not exist. My question is what is bad formed in this sentences. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code. The most pressing is that your update statements are malformed, as indicated by the `ORA-00927: missing equal sign` messages.

```
UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET(ULTIMO) SELECT :NEW.TEXT0 FROM ESC.MENSAJES;
```

is not valid; firstly you need an equals sign for the assignment as part of [the *update-set* clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm#i2126876); secondly you do not select new/old pseudorecord values from their original table, you just refer directly to the `:new.<column>`: thirdly your table definition says the column name is `texto` not `text0`.

```
UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET ULTIMO = :NEW.TEXTO;
```

Similarly in the second update, you're missing an equals sign, and you can only set multiple values in parentheses with a subquery:

```
UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET CUANTOS_MENSAJES = CUANTOS_MENSAJES - 1, ULTIMO = NULL
```

Your third and fourth updates are presumably intended to update the message count for *both* kinds, and has similar other issues; the third is also goign to update all rows in the table, which isn't what you want, so you probably want something like:

```
IF(:OLD.tipo != :NEW.tipo) THEN
  UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET CUANTOS_MENSAJES = CUANTOS_MENSAJES - 1, ULTIMO = NULL
  WHERE :OLD.tipo = tipo;
END IF;
UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET CUANTOS_MENSAJES = CUANTOS_MENSAJES + 1, UNLTIMO = :NEW.TEXT0
WHERE :NEW.tipo = tipo;
```

So althogether, something more like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTUALIZA_TB_MENS_INFO 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON MENSAJES 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET ULTIMO = :NEW.TEXTO;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET CUANTOS_MENSAJES = CUANTOS_MENSAJES - 1, ULTIMO = NULL
    WHERE :OLD.tipo = tipo;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    IF(:OLD.tipo != :NEW.tipo) THEN
      UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET CUANTOS_MENSAJES = CUANTOS_MENSAJES - 1, ULTIMO = NULL
      WHERE :OLD.tipo = tipo;
    END IF;
    UPDATE MENSAJES_INFO SET CUANTOS_MENSAJES = CUANTOS_MENSAJES + 1, ULTIMO = :NEW.TEXTO
    WHERE :NEW.tipo = tipo;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

I've also removed unnecessary parentheses. Read more about [the update statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm), [triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7004.htm) and [pseudorecords](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955).

Trying to maintain counts and other aggregate information via triggers can give you headaches though, as simultaneous operations against `MENSAJES` may leave the `MENSAJES_INFO` table in a state you don't expect unless access is serialised. A view over the base table would be simpler for the counts:

```
CREATE VIEW MENSAJES_INFO AS
SELECT TIPO, COUNT(*) AS CUANTOS_MENSAJES
FROM MENSAJES
GROUP BY TIPO;
```

... but that won't help with `ULTIMO`...

Comment: Alex, your code work. I learn about your comments. .I am a student studying a degree in "computer engineering". I have my exam about ORACLE in one hour. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: @VanesaGarcía - PonderStibbons' answer brings up the important issue if whether you will always already have a record in `MENSAJES_INFO` for every `TIPO`.. If not, this (and your original) won't insert new records into that table for a never-before-seen `TIPO`. Look into using `merge`, as Ponder demonstrates, if you need to deal with that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that storing number of messages for each type in separate table is good idea, You can always select such data. But if You insist please try something like this:

```
create or replace trigger actualiza_tb_mens_info
  after delete or insert or update on mensajes
  for each row

begin
  if inserting then

    merge into mensajes_info mi
    using (select :new.tipo tipo, :new.texto texto from dual) m
    on (mi.tipo = m.tipo)
    when matched then update set
      cuantos_mensajes = cuantos_mensajes + 1, ultimo = m.texto
    when not matched then
      insert (tipo, cuantos_mensajes, ultimo) values (m.tipo, 1, m.texto);

  elsif deleting then

    update mensajes_info set
        cuantos_mensajes = cuantos_mensajes - 1, ultimo = null
      where tipo = :old.tipo;

  elsif updating then
    if :old.tipo != :new.tipo then

      update mensajes_info set
          cuantos_mensajes = cuantos_mensajes - 1, ultimo = null
        where tipo = :old.tipo;

      merge into mensajes_info mi
      using (select :new.tipo tipo, :new.texto texto from dual) m
      on (mi.tipo = m.tipo)
      when matched then update set
        cuantos_mensajes = cuantos_mensajes + 1, ultimo = m.texto
      when not matched then
        insert (tipo, cuantos_mensajes, ultimo) values (m.tipo, 1, m.texto);

    else

      update mensajes_info set ultimo = :new.texto 
        where tipo = :new.tipo;

    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

When inserting use `merge` statement, when deleting correct `update`, when updating - it depends on whether type of message changes or not.

Test:

```
insert into mensajes (codigo, texto, tipo) values (1, 'Text 1', 'Type 1');
insert into mensajes (codigo, texto, tipo) values (2, 'Text 11', 'Type 1');  
insert into mensajes (codigo, texto, tipo) values (3, 'Text 12', 'Type 1');
insert into mensajes (codigo, texto, tipo) values (4, 'Text 21', 'Type 2');

delete from mensajes where codigo = 2;

update mensajes set tipo = 'Type 2' where codigo = 3;

select * from mensajes_info;

TIPO    CUANTOS_MENSAJES  ULTIMO
------  ----------------  --------------------
Type 1                 1  
Type 2                 2  Text 12
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn´t know the sentences "merge into..."